# How to plot a scalar function with a vector argument?

Tags: plotting, vector, arguments

I'm trying to take a simple dot product of two vectors and plotting it as a 3D density plot. However, I don't know how I should define the limits of the plot if the argument of the function is a vector. I want to make the lower and upper limits of the plot, for instance, 0 and 10 for each component of a three coordinate vector Q={Qx,Qy,Qz}. This is the code I have so far and wondered if anybody could be of help:

```
Clear[MyFunction]
MyFunction[Q_] := Dot[Q, Q];
DensityPlot3D[MyFunction[Q], ?]
```

? is where I would like to say that the limits of the plot are from 0 to 10 for all Qx, Qy and Qz.

Comment: `DensityPlot3D[
 MyFunction[{x, y, z}], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f]
Q = {x, y, z};
f[Q_] := Dot[Q, Q];

f[Q]
(*x^2 + y^2 + z^2*)


DensityPlot3D[f[Q], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]